# How to use formatvalue filter for field in form template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In Django templates, we use the filter on value fields such as
 `{{value | formatvalue}}`

I want to generate my form dynamically like the example below.

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

As you know, the `field` attribute will be generated as an html element. Is there a way to add a filter to a `field` value? 

Thanks in advance.